# How to create a TLS certificate request with Scapy including the certauth field

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to create a certificate request with scapy for a tls entry but I can't create one because I keep getting errors when the certauth field is set.

This are the fields definitions from scapy:

```py
FieldLenField("certauthlen", None, fmt="!H", length_of="certauth"),
_CertAuthoritiesField("certauth", [], length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.certauthlen)]
```

When I use a list of strings I get this error:

```py
    ValueError: While dissecting field 'msg': While dissecting field 'certauthlen': Incorrect type of value for field certauthlen:
    struct.error('required argument is not an integer')
    To inject bytes into the field regardless of the type, use RawVal. See help(RawVal)
```

I got these errors when using bytes or a string:

```py
    TypeError: While dissecting field 'msg': While dissecting field 'certauthlen': 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I got this error when using _CertAuthoritiesField directly or a list of them:

```py
    certauth=[_CertAuthoritiesField("asdas")]
    TypeError: StrLenField.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'
```

```py
from scapy.layers.tls.handshake import TLSCertificateRequest
cert_request = TLSCertificateRequest(
    ctypeslen=3, 
    ctypes=[1,2,64], 
    sig_algs_len=30, 
    sig_algs=[0x0601,0x0602, 0x0603, 0x0501, 0x0502, 0x0503, 0x0401, 0x0402, 0x0403, 0x0301, 0x0302,0x0303, 0x0201,0x0202,0x0203],
    certauth=????
)
```

It would be nice if anybody could tell me how I could to this.

Comment: General tip: when in doubt, parse an existing packet with Scapy (a cert..) and use `.command()` to see how it's built